# Storing data in Redux state: reflection of API object vs. simplified form state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Suppose I have a `Report` model in my backend, which has a `date` property, which is of type `Date`. The React form consists of two inputs to modify it: a `<select>` with months and an `<input>` for the date's year in `YYYY` format. I don't care about the day, since I'll set the date to end of the selected month in the selected year using `moment.utc(...).endOf('month')`.

For this task I see two options:

1. My Redux state holds the final computed `date` object, which will be posted to the backend, or
2. The state has two propeties: `month` and `year` and then, when the `Report` is ready to be posted to the backend these two properties get removed and transformed into a `date` object.

Option (2) seems dirty and requires a lot of pre-processing: destructing of the received `Report` object into properties that don't belong in the backend, as well as constucting required properties prior to being posted to the server.

However, option (2) allows for cleaner binding of React's components to the state via `onChange` and `value` properties of the components.

Option (1) seems more sensible, since the Redux state is a representation of the backend's state, however I find myself writing a lot of *hacky* logic:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';

import { reportChange } from '../actions';

const months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

class Report extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleMonthChange = this.handleMonthChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleMonthChange(event) {
    const { dispatch, report } = this.props,
      { target: { value }} = event,
      date = moment.utc(report.date),
      year = this.yearInput.value,
      month = value;
    date.month(month).year(year).endOf('month');
    dispatch(reportChange({
      date: date.toDate()
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { report } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <select name="month" value={moment.utc(report.date).format('M')} onChange={this.handleMonthChange}>
          {months.map((month, index) => (<option key={index} value={index + 1}>{month}</option>))}
        </select>
        <input
          name="year"
          value={moment.utc(report.date).format('YYYY')} // this sets initial value of the input
          ref={input => this.yearInput = input} // uncontrolled component
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    report: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  report: state.report
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Report);
```

This is a short version with all unnecessary stuff removed. Now, as you can see, I've used an [uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) for the year input. This is because if I bind it to the original `date` property in the `Report` object in Redux store via `value={moment.utc(report.date).format('YYYY')}` and `onChange` properties the component gets unusable, it is always bound to that `YYYY` format, so you can't delete any digit — it gets automatically updated to `0201` instead of `201` when you hit backspace to remove `7` from `2017`.

Moreover, since this is an uncontrolled component, I have to manually extract its value in all significant events, like the `form`'s `onSubmit` event handler to update the report object before submitting with a proper date, etc.

I feel like I'm missing something and there should be an easier way. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option (1) seems more sensible, since the Redux state is a representation of the backend's state

I would argue. The Redux state should represent the state of your app (whatever it is, including UI state that is not stored on the backend). So, option (2) is way to go. Also, it makes component reusable because they don't depend on the backend data format.

Comment: Ok, so I've rewritten my app so that Redux state corresponds to my view logic rather than to the backend. Although I can't seem to figure out where (according to React and Redux philosophy) I should store the transformation of the backend state to the Redux state. Currently, backend-to-redux is in my reducers, since it accepts the final `RECEIVE_REPORT` action, and redux-to-backend is in actions, since it dispatches the final `save` action. Maybe I should try middleware though.

Answer (score 1):

I do strongly disagree with the idea that component state should closely map related `Redux` (`Flux`, whichever) state. Mixing view logic with domain logic always leads to this kind of complications.

It's almost always [A Good Thing](http://wiki.c2.com/?GoodThing) to use data format that is convenient for view logic in view code and another data format for domain logic code. And implement necessary bridging code to translate one into another (with proper validation and alike). `react-redux`, which you are currently using, provides two places for such a conversion: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

If you let your view code (React component) have it's own life with it's own state, you'll solve another kind of complication that you mentioned, namely, fighting with unwanted year field updates.

I fixed your code to let it look in a way i described, but **be aware** I didn't run it actually, so some fixes may be needed:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';

import { reportChange } from '../actions';

const months = [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

class Report extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { month: props.month, year: props.year }; 
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ month: nextProps.month });
  }

  handleMonthChange(month) {
    this.setState({ month });
    props.onChange(month, this.state.year);
  }

  handleYearChange(year) {
    this.setState({ year });
    props.onChange(this.state.month, year);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          name="month"
          value={this.state.month}
          onChange={e => this.handleMonthChange(e.target.value)}
        >
          {months.map((month, index) => (<option key={index} value={index + 1}>{month}</option>))}
        </select>

        <input
          name="year"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.year}
          onChange={e => handleYearChange(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    month: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    year: PropTypes.string.isRequierd,
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const date = state.report.date;
  return {
    month: moment.utc(date).format('M'),
    year: moment.utc(date).format('YYYY'),
  };
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onChange: (month, year) => {
    const date = date.month(month).year(year).endOf('month').toDate();
    dispatch(reportChange({ date })),
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Report);
```

Comment: Ok, so by _domain_ you mean the _Redux state_ which is a representation of the backend's state and that I should give my components their own local state which will get synced with the Redux state according to some rules? Isn't it easier to get rid of the local state, make Redux state correspond to the view components (instead of the backend) and then transform Redux state into backend state before sending it to the server (my option 2)? And, hence, transform backend state to Redux state upon receiving it from the server.

Comment: _Domain logic_ is the logic of how your data is created, how it updated and disposed. In most production-quality apps there is a plenty of it. Do you have inter-reducers communication? Do you have any transformation of data which is not caused by needs of presenting it to user or sending to server? If your answer is no and your client is really thin (limited to just getting stuff from server and sending it back) then your option 2 is probably a way to go.